# How to subscribe to a Websocket topic in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

The problem is that I can't find a solution for subscribing to a WebSocket topic.

I've tried **web_socket_channel**, but there was no needed functionality for subscribing to a specific topic.

Also, I've tried **stomp_sockjs**, but it requires SDK version <2.0.0. My current Dart SDK version is 2.4.0 and I don't want to lower it because it would break all the other dependencies I have.

In other WebSocket libraries like **adhara_socket_io**, I can't find a method to subscribe for a topic.

I managed to consume the data from WebSocket using JS with help of **sockjs** and **stomp** libraries. But how to do that in flutter?

```
function connect() {
            stompClient = Stomp.client("ws://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/somePath");
            stompClient.connect({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"}, function (frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/someStatus', function (greeting) {
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
                });
            });
        }
```

So, I want to find a solution that would do the same but in my flutter app

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets don't have a concept of topics - the protocol you're using in JS is called [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/) so you'd need to use a STOMP library for Dart.

There are some STOMP packages on Pub, but I don't know how complete (or trustworthy) they are:

- https://pub.dev/packages/stomp
- https://pub.dev/packages/stomp_client

The S in STOMP stands for Simple though, so if neither work it might not be too difficult to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'have found the solution: https://github.com/killerWqs2/flutter-websocket-client

It allows subscribing to a stomp topic via WebSockets

Comment: Have you used with stomp? did it work with stomp? @user3473445